# Including attributes in custom Rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I hope the title is not to misleading, as I don't know a better title for the problem I'm working on:

I have a doctor which belongs to location and specialty. I'd like to route to show action of the doc controller like this:

/dentist/berlin/7

I defined my routes like this:

```
get ':specialty/:location/:id', to: 'docs#show'
```

And in my views create the following url to link to the show action of the doc controller:

```
<%= link_to doc.name, "#{doc.specialty.name}/#{doc.location.name}/#{doc.id}" %>
```

Is this a good solution to the problem? If not, is there a cleaner way to construct urls like this possibly using resources? What the heck is the name for a this problem?

Thank your very much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For references, you should have a look at [this page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) (especially [the end of section 2.6](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing))

If it is only for a single route, it's okay as you did. But then if you want to have more than one route (like `/dentist/berlin/7`, `/dentist/berlin/7/make_appointment`, etc.) you might want to structure a bit more your routes so as to take advantage of rails `resources`.

For example, instead of

```
get ':specialty/:location/:id', to: 'doctors#show'
get ':specialty/:location/:id/appointment', to: 'doctors#new_appointment'
post ':specialty/:location/:id/appointment', to: 'doctors#post_appointment'
```

You could have something like this (the code is almost equivalent, see explanation below)

```
resources :doctors, path: '/:specialty/:location', only: [:show] do
  member do
    get 'new_appointment' 
    post 'create_appointment'
  end
end
```

**Explanation**

- `resources` will generate the RESTful routes (index, show, edit, new, create, destroy) for the specified controller (`doctors_controller` I assume)
- The 'only' means you don't want to add all the RESTful routes, just the ones specified
- Then you want to add `member` actions, ie. actions that can be executed on a particular item of the collection. You can chose different syntaxes

  ```
  resources :doctors do
    member do 
      # Everything here will have the prefix /:id so the action applies to a particular item
    end
  end
  # OR
  resources :doctors do
    get 'new_appointement', on: :member
  end
  ```
- By default, the controller action is the same as the path name you give, but you can also override it

  ```
  member do
    get 'appointment', action: 'new_appointment'
    post 'appointment', action: 'post_appointment'
  end
  ```

Rails has some wonderful helpers when it comes to routing !

Comment: Thanks Cyril, that was exactly what I was looking for: solving the problem using resources.

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach is to give your route a name, like this:

```
get ':specialty/:location/:id', to: 'docs#show', as: 'docs_show'
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
<%= link_to doc.name, docs_show_path(doc.specialty.name, doc.location.name, doc.id)  %>
```

Note 1:
Rails appends `_path` at the end of the route names you define.

Note 2:
You can see all the available named routes by executing `rake routes`.

Comment: Thanks Mihai, that helped a lot.